# Using setComplete

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

So for my assignment, I'm using the method setComplete. The instructions for this is: For the task with the given name, mark it as complete. If the Task doesn't exist, then do nothing.

The code is this:

```
/**
 * @param name the name of the task to mark complete ( set complete = true).
 */
public void setComplete(String name)
{

    //your code here

}
```

I have no idea how to proceed. Any tips would be helpful. Additionally, non-related to this part, I don't know how to print a numbered list??
example: I want to print the following:

```
1. name of first incomplete task
2. name of second incomplete task
3. .......
4. ......etc.
```

I can print a list, just don't know how to number it.

Thank you!

Comment: I think what I'm trying to ask is simply how to utilize the setComplete method. It's the first time I see this, and I don't quite understand what it does, thus I don't know how to utilize it at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're not explaining yourself well. Considering your second question, it seems like you have a list of tasks (maybe a list of Task objects), and have to set the task with the given name as complete.
You simply have to iterate over the list, and check if the task name is the same as the one you're given in the parameter. If it is, then set that task to complete.

In regards to your second question, well.. If you know how to print the incomplete tasks, simply keep a counter variable, increment it every time you find an incomplete task and print it along with the task name.

Comment: Have you read the assignment? setComplete seems to be a function that should be implemented by you. It sets a task as complete, within the context of your program. That simple.